# monit service permission starting a linux service

Tags: permissions, monitoring, upload, service, monit

I'm running monit to monitor a linux service i wrote which basically makes sure that a mounted partition exist.

the service start action is: `mount -a`

the service stop action is: `umount /...../....`

When i'm running the service manually everything works fine but when monit is starting the service i dont have permissions to upload files through my web application.

Is there any special permissions monit is running the service (mount) with?

### EDIT:

My setup is to start the service is a simple init script with start and stop (which is mount -a and umount respectively)

Thanks,
Danny

Comment: When monit starts the service are file systems mounted ? Here i am trying to determine if `mount -a` is executed by monit. Also, an update of your question with your setup for this service will help (maybe)

Comment: @user2196728, yes monit starts the service and the FS is mounted (but with no permission to write files through the web to that partition.